# Is a circuit serving a combination exhaust fan, light, and heater still considered dedicated?

Tags: electrical

Can you connect wires from the panel to a junction box and install a heat vent light and it is considered dedicated?

Comment: It's not clear how your question is different from the one you originally posted on. Please explain your concern in more detail if it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Is "a heat vent light" your words for a combination exhaust fan unit? If so, that's a single device/fixture with just one connection point. So yes, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it only powers the heat vent light.  You only use the box for a splice in the wires.

Running another cable to something else from the box from the same breaker, would be a no.

So you want one breaker, one wire pathway only powering the device.  A junction box just used for a splice in the wires is okay.